# в canvas не перемещается картинка, img is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, html5, canvas, изображения

я загружаю картинку с компьютера, а потом хочу по нажатии кнопки поднять ее вверх, почему JS говорит что картинка не определена?

```js
function draw() { //upload
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'),
    img = new Image(),
    f = document.getElementById("uploadimage").files[0],
    url = window.zURL || window.URL,
    src = url.createObjectURL(f);
  img.src = src;
  img.onload = function() {
    //ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
   // ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height) ;
   ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,0,0,canvas.width,(img.height*canvas.width)/img.width);//вписывание в ширину
  }
}
document.getElementById("uploadimage").addEventListener("change", draw, false)

function qwe() { 
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,0,-500,canvas.width,(img.height*canvas.width)/img.width);//вписывание в ширину
}
```

```html
<button onclick="qwe()">Move </button>
 <input type="file" name="img" id="uploadimage" size="1" class="input_input_style">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1200" height="1000"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас в функции `qwe()` не указана переменная `img`

```js
var img;
function draw() { //upload
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  img = new Image();
  var f = document.getElementById("uploadimage").files[0],
      url = window.zURL || window.URL,
      src = url.createObjectURL(f);
  img.src = src;
  img.onload = function() {
    //ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
   // ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height) ;
   ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,0,0,canvas.width,(img.height*canvas.width)/img.width);//вписывание в ширину
  };
};
document.getElementById("uploadimage").addEventListener("change", draw, false)

function qwe() { 
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,0,-500,canvas.width,(img.height*canvas.width)/img.width);//вписывание в ширину
}
```

```html
<button onclick="qwe()">Move </button>
 <input type="file" name="img" id="uploadimage" size="1" class="input_input_style">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1200" height="1000"></canvas>
```